# Connecting to Web Host using SSH?

Tags: ssh, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I want to connect to my Web Host via SSH, it worked fine the first time, but then I wanted to mount my host's drive locally, I found **"sshfs"** so I ran this command:

```
sshfs -o allow_other,default_permissions username@host:/home2/ulogcbug/localDrive /mnt/ulogcbug/
```

Which didn't work, It didn't respond for a while then returned a timeout error

So I decided it wasn't worth the trouble, then I went back to use ssh normally

I ran the same command for connecting to ssh that I used the first time:

```
ssh user@host
```

But now I get this error msg:

```
ssh: connect to host host_adr_here port 722: Connection timed out
```

Note: the first time when it worked I was using the default port which is 22 and it worked, then after I tried it the second time and it didn't work I remember my Web Host uses Port 722 for SSH, so I changed it in ** /etc/ssh/ssh_config ** but I get the same error

**Update: i swiched to another wifi network then it worked again, but when i ran the SSHFS command it stopped working again, any ideas on how to fix this ? for example how to stop all that sshfs is doing ?**

Comment: It's not possible that it worked on port 22 if your host actually uses port 722. Also you shouldn't be changing anything in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` to get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soo, I found out what was wrong and it's pretty dumb.., My Ip was dynamic, so when I changed to wifi that was using static IPs, it worked just fine.
But The weird Thing is it works even with port 22 Which is really confusing.